# WordPress Auto Login After Custom Registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WP registration script that works nicely, although I can't get it to automatically login the user. I can confirm that it creates the user profile. I've also tried triggering wp_signon() with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
function complete_registration() {
    global $reg_errors, $username, $password, $email;
    if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
        $data = array(
            'user_login'    =>   $username,
            'user_email'    =>   $email,
            'user_pass'     =>   $password
        );
        $user = wp_insert_user( $data );

        if(!is_wp_error($user))
            wp_set_current_user($user);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This function you have, what action are you hooking into it with?

Comment: It's part of a few functions but ultimately it's called by a shortcode:

add_shortcode( 'user_registration', 'user_registration_function' );

function user_registration_function() {
    ob_start();
    custom_registration_function();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

Comment: Sorry got cut off; within that custom_registration_function(), it sanitizes the form information and passes it to the complete_registration() function.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the headers have already been sent. Can you try performing a header redirect as a test to see if it follows through? if it does, then there's something else going on, if it doesn't, then you're too late in the execution chain, perhaps.

Comment: Um it didn't redirect but it didn't give me any errors either.

Comment: Ah I take that back, you were right, it was a header issue. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

Function was triggering too late in the execution chain.

Answer (score 0):

have same functions for custom register form from [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-wordpress-registration-form-plugin--cms-20968) and want to use same option for autologin and its not work also because header already send.. so just add this code and it will work..

```
add_action('init', 'custom_registration_shortcode');
```